# Workaround for click() not working in HtmlUnitDriver in Fitnesse?

Tags: java, firefox, click, htmlunit, fitnesse

I have a jUnit test running a Fitnesse test that tests some web pages. When in development mode, I use the FirefoxDriver and all tests run great, with web pages popping up as expected.

When I try to run the test in an automated mode, i.e. using Maven, the tests fail miserably. Do any of you have any suggestions of what might be wrong or a workaround?

The relevant code:
- The web page:

```
      <form method="get" action="/someAction.do" name="my_form">  
      <input id="fetch_new_submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit" onclick="showWaitMsg()" value="Fetch new orders" role="button">  
      </form>
```

- The fixturecode:
      class SomeFixture...

  ```
  public boolean pressSubmitButton(String buttonText) {
  try {
     List<WebElement> buttons = getWebDriver().findElements(By.tagName("input"));
     for (WebElement button : buttons) {
         if (button.getAttribute("value").equals(buttonText)) {
             System.out.println("found button '" + button.getAttribute("value") + "'.");
             button.click(); //HERE
             return true;
         }
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     LOG.debug("Some error occured, e);
     return false;
  }
  LOG.debug("Did not find the button");
  return false;
  }
  ```

Note:
- getWebDriver() returning FirefoxDriver works fine.
- getWebDriver returning new HtmlUnitDriver(true) i.e. with javascript enabled, ignores the button.click() at HERE. Button.submit() is also ignored here and button.sendKeys("\n") throws an element 'not enabled'-error.
- we use version 2.0rc2

Our automated tests can't use FirefoxDriver. Are there any known workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Further testing and usage of bleeding edge, i.e. snapshots gave me something that works for now.

That is:
 - upgraded Selenium to 2.0rc3
 - upgraded htmlunit to 2.9 SNAPSHOT !!!

And some more experimenting around:

```
final HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
```

The Firefox version now works for submit type buttons but fails for javascript actions. This could also be due to me using Firefox_3_6 version driver while using Firefox 4.0.1. browser.

The IE version_8 hangs on click().

But, the plain HtmlUnitDriver() works!